# Schematic representation of a ring homomorphism

Tags: diagrams

I would like to learn to make a schematic representation of a ring homomorphism like the one given in the following image.

[image]

I searched and found nothing useful. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! There are already many similar questions, many of which have excellent answers. This answer attempts to make drawing the potato-shaped boundaries a bit more convenient. Given a set of objects in a `local bounding box`, it draws a somewhat irregular, ellipse-shaped boundary around that `local bounding box`. The corresponding scopes can be used for other purposes such as attaching a `name prefix`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.4pt,outer sep=0pt},
    >={Stealth[bend,length=4.5pt,inset=1pt]}]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,name prefix=R-]
   \path node[bullet,label=above:$a$](a){}
    (1,0.6) node[bullet,label=above:$b$](b){}
    (-0.2,-1) node[bullet,label=below:$a+b$](aplusb){}
    (1.3,-0.8) node[bullet,label=below:$a\cdot b$](adotb){};
  \end{scope}
  \pgfmathsetseed{42}
  \draw plot[smooth cycle,domain=0:330,samples=11,variable=\t,tension=0.7] 
   ([xshift={0.25*(1+rnd)*cos(\t)*1cm+0.75*cos(\t)*1cm},
    yshift={0.5*(1+rnd)*sin(\t)*1cm}]R.\t);
  %
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=S,xshift=6cm,name prefix=S-]
   \path node[bullet,label=above:$\phi(a)$](a){}
    (1.4,0.4) node[bullet,label=above:$\phi(b)$](b){}
    (0.2,-1.3) node[bullet,label=below:$\phi(a+b)$](aplusb){}
    (1.6,-0.6) node[bullet,label=below:$\phi(a\cdot b)$](adotb){};
  \end{scope}
  \draw plot[smooth cycle,domain=0:330,samples=11,variable=\t,tension=0.7] 
   ([xshift={0.25*(1+rnd)*cos(\t)*1cm+0.75*cos(\t)*1cm},
    yshift={0.5*(1+rnd)*sin(\t)*1cm}]S.\t);
  %
  \path (R.120) node[above=2.5em]{$R$} (S.60) node[above=2.5em]{$S$};
  \begin{scope}[->]
   \begin{scope}[dashed]
     \foreach \X in {R,S}
     {\draw (\X-a) -- (\X-aplusb);
     \draw (\X-b) -- (\X-adotb);
     \draw (\X-a) -- (\X-adotb);
     \draw (\X-b) -- (\X-aplusb);
     }
    \end{scope} 
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {a,b,adotb,aplusb}
    {\draw (R-\X) to[bend right={sign(\Y-2.5)*20}] 
        node[above,pos={0.5+0.1*pow(-1,\Y)*sign(\Y-2.5)}]{$\phi$} (S-\X);}   
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a general comment, it is not really the purpose of this site to convert screen shots into LaTeX code. Of course, such question often receive answers, but users will generally benefit more from more conceptual questions, in which the OP posts a concrete code that shows what they have tried.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Thank you!